# How to send custom Header in async functions used is Ant design pro?

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

i want to send custom headers with async request  i am using React And design pro framework .

```
export async function AccountLogin(params) {
  console.log('params', params);
  return request('http://dreamfactory.com/api/v2/user/session', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'X-DreamFactory-Api-Key': '36fda24fe5588fa4285ac6c6c2fdfbdb6b6bc9834699774c9bf777f706d05a88',
    },
    body: params,
  });
}
```

Comment: And Design Pro uses isomorphic-fetch internally, I think your code is right.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by jQuery.You can set a parameter headers to jQuery ajax, just like the code below

```js
export async function AccountLogin(params) {
     $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://dreamfactory.com/api/v2/user/session",
      data:params,
      headers:{
     'X-DreamFactory-Api-Key': '36fda24fe5588fa4285ac6c6c2fdfbdb6b6bc9834699774c9bf777f706d05a88',
      }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
  }
```

[jquery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Can you please give me an example how do i use this with my code ?

Comment: check the renew example